# How to use ternary operator just as if statement?

Tags: c++

I want to use ternary operator("? : ") as if statement statement.To be precise I want to do something like this,if(temp>0) so increment 'i' else do nothing.

```
          temp?i++:WHAT_SHOULD_COME_HERE_SO_NO_CHANGES_ARE_MADE_ANYWHERE
```

Comment: Then don't use a ternary operator...?

Comment: `?` represents an `if...else`.  if you just have an `if` why not use `if (condition) action;`

Comment: You can't leave the "else" part blank.

Comment: `0`'s good, I guess.

Comment: @NathanOliver Because its one liner

Comment: @PankajMishra What I wrote is also one line.  Nothing says `action` needs to be on its one line.

Comment: @PankajMishra - So is `if (condition) action;`. And it's far less "clever".

Comment: Also, be careful about evaluating `temp` as a raw boolean...  if `temp` could ever be negative, then strictly speaking `if (temp)` and `if (temp > 0)` are not equivalent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Answer

Strictly speaking, you can't do this:

```
(boolean expression) ? (returning expression) : /* no-op */;
```

*Something* has to go in the third operand.  However, you can make that "something" behaviorally equivalent to a no-op in terms of the post-conditions of evaluating the ternary operator.  See below.

---

## Explanation

The ternary operator must return a value, and the type is deduced as the most derived type that is a supertype of the return type of each of the second and third operands.  So if the third operand is a blank expression (i.e. it returns nothing), then the compiler cannot deduce a return type for the operator as a whole.  Thus, it will not compile.

---

## Solution

**Using the ternary operator:**

If you really wanted to, this is how you might do it using the ternary operator:

```
i = temp>0 ? i+1 : i;
```

or

```
temp>0 ? ++i : i;
```

**Preferred syntax:**

Although if all you're looking for is a one-liner, then the following syntax is preferred:

```
if (temp>0) ++i;
```

Comment: for the second option, just get rid of the braces if you're going to do that. Also note that the parentheses in the first are redundant

Comment: @AndrewLi I've gotten in the habit of using the the parentheses and braces for the sake of readability, especially whenever the sub-expressions are multi-operator expressions.  (better visual delineation)  Although you're right, I guess in this case that doesn't apply.

Comment: @anatolyg No, you literally *can't* "do nothing" in the third operand if the second operand returns a value.  *Something* must go there.  The behavioral effect may be equivalent to a no-op (as both other answers *as well as my answer* show), but the third operand *cannot* "do nothing" if the second operand returns a value.

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
(void) ((temp>0)?i++:0);
```

Note that the (void) does not change the behavior of the code; rather it is there to indicate to the reader (and/or any style checking programs you might invoke in the future) that the result of the expression is being deliberately discarded.  Without it you may get warnings from the compiler and/or other programmers suspecting a bug and trying to "fix" your code.

Actually, you may get that anyway, since the above is a very unusual way to express what you are trying to do.  The code will be easier for others to understand and maintain if you instead use the traditional form:

```
if (temp>0) i++;
```

Comment: The part with `void` casting doesn't work. If you want to use the casting, add parentheses around the whole expression (however, that will make it ugly).

Comment: You're right; I've added the parentheses.  It was already ugly so nothing is lost there.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator is used in an expression. As such, the entire expression must evaluate to a single value. This means that you must supply both the "if" and "else" clauses. There is no way to leave the "else" part blank.

In addition, embedding an increment operator within an expression such as this is inadvisable since the consequences of the side-effect are so error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

you can:

```
    int temp = 20, i = 0;

    (temp)? i++: i;

    cout << i << endl;
```